# PhpStorm HTML, JS and CSS syntax highlighting in PHP files

Tags: php, html, css, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

it it possible to highlight HTML, JS and CSS syntax in PHP files in PhpStorm from JetBrains?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which version do you use? I'm using 9.0.1 and there is HTML highlighting in PHP files.

Comment: 9.0.2 has been released -- see if it will fix the issue for you.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks!!! for the notice, 9.0.2 resolved the problem!